# Running project in IntelliJ

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, maven, intellij-idea

I have one application based on Maven + Spring.
It's a Java web application using java.

this is the pom.xml i'm using:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.alfred</groupId>
<artifactId>alfred</artifactId>
<version>v.0.1-CID.Fase.II.Edesk-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<name>ALFRED</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Dependencia para Spring DATA JPA con base de datos -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Para implementar las conexiones a la base de datos MySQL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <!-- version>5.1.35</version -->
    </dependency>


    <!-- Para implementar el servicio REST -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->

    <!-- Paquete que permite convertir el contenido de una respuesta en texto 
        plano JSON a objetos Java. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Para implementar cliente REST con Template -->
    <!-- dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId> 
        </dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Para implementar las plantillas HTML con thymeleaf -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf.extras/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Para poder implementar los clientes de los servicios REST -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit</groupId>
        <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Para escapar HTML en las llamadas a la API de IMDB -->
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Java Mail API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-ldap -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Librería para tratar con excels -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.16</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <!--<plugin> <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration> DO NOT include log4j.properties file in your Jar <excludes>
            <exclude>**/log4j.properties</exclude> </excludes> <archive> </archive> </configuration> 
            </plugin> -->
    </plugins>
</build>


</project>
```

When I do the clean, generate resources and install appear this error and not start working

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin\java"
>   -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Users\spainasg\Documents\CID_UAT
>   -Dmaven.home=C:\Users\spainasg\Downloads\apache-maven-3.5.2-bin\apache-maven-3.5.2 -Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Users\spainasg\Downloads\apache-maven-3.5.2-bin\apache-maven-3.5.2\bin\m2.conf
>   -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\spainasg\Downloads\apache-maven-3.5.2-bin\apache-maven-3.5.2\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar
>   org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2017.2.6 --offline -s
>   C:\Users\spainasg.m2\settings.xml
>   -Dmaven.repo.local=C:\Users\spainasg.m2\repository clean generate-resources install
>       [INFO] Scanning for projects...
>       [WARNING] 
>       [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for
>   com.alfred:alfred:war:v.0.1-CID.Fase.II.Edesk-SNAPSHOT
>       [WARNING] Detected profiles.xml alongside com.alfred:alfred:v.0.1-CID.Fase.II.Edesk-SNAPSHOT, this file is no
>   longer supported and was ignored, please use the settings.xml instead
>       [WARNING] 
>       [WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
>       [WARNING] 
>       [WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
>       [WARNING] 
>       [INFO] 
>       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>       [INFO] Building ALFRED v.0.1-CID.Fase.II.Edesk-SNAPSHOT
>       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>       [WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.5.2 is missing, no
>   dependency information available
>       [WARNING] The POM for com.oracle:ojdbc14:jar:10.2.0.4.0 is missing, no dependency information available
>       [WARNING] The POM for org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE
>   is missing, no dependency information available
>       [WARNING] The POM for org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.16 is missing, no dependency information available
>       [WARNING] The POM for org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:3.16 is missing, no dependency information available
>       [WARNING] The POM for com.github.virtuald:curvesapi:jar:1.04 is missing, no dependency information available
>       [INFO] 
>       [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ alfred ---
>       [INFO] Deleting C:\Users\spainasg\Documents\CID_UAT\target
>       [INFO] 
>       [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ alfred ---
>       [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
>       [INFO] Copying 1 resource
>       [INFO] Copying 90 resources
>       [INFO] 
>       [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ alfred ---
>       [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
>       [INFO] Compiling 174 source files to C:\Users\spainasg\Documents\CID_UAT\target\classes
>       [WARNING] /C:/Users/spainasg/Documents/CID_UAT/src/main/java/com/edesk/controladorGUI/GestionServicioAprobadorController.java:
>   C:\Users\spainasg\Documents\CID_UAT\src\main\java\com\edesk\controladorGUI\GestionServicioAprobadorController.java
>   uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
>       [WARNING] /C:/Users/spainasg/Documents/CID_UAT/src/main/java/com/edesk/controladorGUI/GestionServicioAprobadorController.java:
>   Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
>       [INFO] 
>       [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ alfred ---
>       [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
>       [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\spainasg\Documents\CID_UAT\src\test\resources
>       [INFO] 
>       [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ alfred ---
>       [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
>       [INFO] 
>       [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) @ alfred ---
>       [WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.surefire:maven-surefire-common:jar:2.17 is missing,
>   no dependency information available
>       [WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-api:jar:2.17 is missing, no
>   dependency information available
>       [WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven:maven-toolchain:jar:2.0.9 is missing, no dependency information available
>       [WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugin-tools:maven-plugin-annotations:jar:3.2 is
>   missing, no dependency information available
>       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>       [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
>       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>       [INFO] Total time: 4.961 s
>       [INFO] Finished at: 2017-11-30T09:45:30+01:00
>       [INFO] Final Memory: 29M/233M
>       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>       [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test
>   (default-test) on project alfred: Execution default-test of goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test failed:
>   Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17 or one of
>   its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could
>   not be resolved:
>   org.apache.maven.surefire:maven-surefire-common:jar:2.17,
>   org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-api:jar:2.17,
>   org.apache.maven:maven-toolchain:jar:2.0.9,
>   org.apache.maven.plugin-tools:maven-plugin-annotations:jar:3.2,
>   org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.1: Cannot access central
>   (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) in offline mode and the
>   artifact org.apache.maven.surefire:maven-surefire-common:jar:2.17 has
>   not been downloaded from it before. -> [Help 1]
>       [ERROR] 
>       [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>       [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>       [ERROR] 
>       [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>       [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
>       [ERROR] Maven execution terminated abnormally (exit code 1)

I'm using IntelliJ, but have the same error using Eclipse.
The aplications are working offline.

Any idea for this solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add all your missing dependencies.

```
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.surefire:maven-surefire-common:jar:2.17 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-api:jar:2.17 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven:maven-toolchain:jar:2.0.9 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugin-tools:maven-plugin-annotations:jar:3.2 is missing, no dependency information available
```